# add rows.name without removing a column in R

Tags: r, csv

I have a data frame in R like this small example:

small example:

```
        CodeClass       Name    Accession       file
1       Endogenous      CCNO    NM_021147.4     5.265025
2       Endogenous      MYC     NM_002467.3     2444.919110
3       Endogenous      CD79A   NM_001783.3     2002.952790
```

rows name are numbers but I want to change it to the column "`Name`" but
still keep the column "`Name`". here is expected output:

expected output:

```
        CodeClass       Name    Accession       file
CCNO    Endogenous      CCNO    NM_021147.4     5.265025
MYC     Endogenous      MYC     NM_002467.3     2444.919110
CD79A   Endogenous      CD79A   NM_001783.3     2002.952790
```

I tried to do that in R using this argument:

```
rows.name("Name")
```

but this argument moves the column "`Name`" to the rows name and removes
the column from data frame. do you know how to get the expected output
in `R`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
rownames(df) <- df$Name
```

Where `df` is the name of your dataframe. See here, for example

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(1:10, ncol= 5))
rownames(df) <- df$X2
df
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
3  1  3  5  7  9
4  2  4  6  8 10
```